# concatenate string with variable in php

Tags: php, concatenation

I declared a variable as `$Catalogurl = "test";` Now I want to concatenate to 'cataloglink' in this line so that the 'link' will be "test"+ the variable in 'cataloglink'. How do I do it?

```
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('cataloglink')->item(0)->nodeValue,
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the concat operator "."
The way to use it is just put both variables you want to concat on both sides of it and that it. So:

```
$hello = "Hello"." World";
```

If you have time I'd recommend looking at the docs, lots of neat stuff in there. http://www.php.net/manual/en

Comment: Thanks Brac. I am quite new to php, I am just using my programming logic to resolve php problems (Drupal)

Answer (score 0):

```
'link' => $Catalogurl . $node->getElementsByTagName('cataloglink')->item(0)->nodeValue,
```

For more info please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php